# crawling issue in my website about two week

Tags: web-crawlers

I almost did this change before 20-21 days but still Google is not crawling Site.

Comment: Duplicate. Also... your pages are indexing just fine: https://imgur.com/a/FnciF - most likely you are attempting 'keyword searches' which is subject to Google Rankings, not Google Bot or Crawling.